# dojo not getting loaded in rhino environmnet

Tags: java, dojo, rhino, server-side-scripting

Im trying to load dojo charts in java program and have came across the example in this [blog](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/dojo-bootstrapping-in-embedded-rhino.html) and tried it but with failure. the reason for dojo not getting loaded I found after a long toil is that the while loop given below (in the dojo.js(uncompressed) line.no:1673 ) is an infinite loop.

```
while(!insertPointSibling){
            if(!/^dojo/.test((script = scripts[i++]) && script.type)){
                insertPointSibling= script;
            }
        }
```

please help me to fix this problem. Im using dojo 1.9